# How Jhipster supports thymeleaf apart from what spring boot does?

Tags: angular, reactjs, thymeleaf, jhipster

How Jhipster supports thymeleaf?
How to generate UI for multi-paged application in thymeleaf using Jhipster generated application. Can we generate basic CRUD UI in thymeleaf as we can do with Angular using Jhipster? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: JHipster does not support generating a Thymeleaf UI, it only generates Angular and React clients

Comment: Strangely enough, JHipster website https://www.jhipster.tech/ does mention Thymeleaf as a supported technology for UI. However, I am not able to find a working example for the same.

Comment: @iCrus I think that must be because SpringBoot supports Thymeleaf

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Jon, JHipster does not support Thymeleaf in the front end, but uses it as template engine for emails generated by the backend, for instance during user registration.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this and I would imagine others have and it appears the new version of jHipster do support Thymeleaf web templates.

https://www.jhipster.tech/tech-stack/

Answer (score 0):

As answered in comment by Jon it is correct that JHipster does not support generating clients other than Angular and React.